# @+id/とはなんですか？

Tags: android

AndroidアプリのUIをXMLで指定するときによく使う `@+id/` ですが、なんでこれだけ `+` が入っているのですか？なんとなくこう書くものだと思って使っていましたが、改めて考えてみるとなんでだろうと思いまして… `@id/` ではなぜいけなかったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「`@+id/`とは何か？」について、完全に理解するには、前提として[`ID Resource`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id)という地味な存在について理解する必要があると考えます。

これは`res/values/`配下に、以下のように定義することができます。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="hoge" />
</resources>
```

個人的に`@+id/hoge`という記法は上記の定義を自動的に行う、糖衣構文の一種だと考えています。

## IDリソースの使い道

`ID Resource`を用いることで`id`のみを定義することができます。

`@id`はほぼ`View`でしか使わず、しかし`View`の`id`は`@+id`で定義をした方がミスが減り品質が担保されるため、使い道はなさそうです。

しかし`ID Resource`はビルド時点で、名前ごとにユニークな値を持つことを保証してくれます。この性質は非常に便利なので頭の片隅に入れておくといつか役に立つかもしれません。

また、全ての`id`を事前にこの方法で定義すれば、参照だけでレイアウトを記述することも可能ですが、実際にやっているという話は聞いたことがないですし、血迷うなとしか言えません。

Comment: この方法が役に立つ場面があります。ビルドフレーバーを使用してlayoutのリソースを切り替える場合です。特定のビルドフレーバーの時にだけ存在するViewに`android:id="@+id/xxx"`の方式でIDを振っている場合に、ビルドフレーバーに依存しないJavaのコードで`R.id.xxx`を使用していると別のビルドフレーバーに切り替えた時にビルドできません。idリソースを共通に作成しておけばこの問題を回避できます。

Answer (score 7):

`@+id` の意味は「新規リソースとして新たに ID を振る」ということです。`+` 記号付きの書き方をすると、整数のリソース ID が自動生成され、R.java に追加されます。

> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file). There are a number of other ID resources that are offered by the Android framework. When referencing an Android resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol, but must add the android package namespace

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id より

参照する場合は `+` 記号を指定せず、代わりに `@id/hoge` のように書きます。個人的には、タイポした場合に発見しやすくするためにも、参照のときは `@+id/hoge` といった書き方ではなく `@id/hoge` という書き方を推奨します。

Comment: 使い分けるケースとしては、相互参照（RelativeLayoutで複数要素がお互いの位置に依存している場合など）が必要なときは@+id/hogeでの定義＆参照が便利ですね。私も必要にならない限りは参照は@id/hogeで書いてます。

Answer (score 4):

@+id/hoge : idを追加で定義する（参照にも使える）
@id/hoge  : idを参照する

と私は理解しています。

RelativeLayoutで使うlayout_below等でIDを参照するような場合では@id/「も」使えます。
ただ、@+idを使っても結局同じ動作になる為、使い分ける必要性がなく@+idのみを使う人が多いのではないかと思います。

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
      tools:text="text2"/>

  <!-- +を使わない場合 -->
  <TextView
      android:id="@id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:text="text1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: この書き方は、まだ定義されていない`text1`を参照しているので、本来はビルドエラーになる気がします。（他の場所で既に`text1`が定義されている、例えば`<item name="text1" type="id" />`を使って、IDをリソース管理している場合など例外はありますが）

Comment: 確かに。既存のプロジェクト上でレイアウト作ったので気づきませんでした。修正しました。